# Is it possible to turn off the visibility of the parent-grid of the tilemap in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to turn off the visibility of the grid of the tilemap. I feel like it's easier to draw and design without grids and I couldn't find any solution to my problem yet. To clarify, I don't mean the main-grid from unity, I know how to change its visibility, I'm talking about the Grid that appears when you create a tilemap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply disable the Grid Gizmo via the Gizmos tab in the Scene View:

[image: GIF of the "grid" component being disabled in the Gizmos menu]

*(The editor I'm using here is Unity 2022.1.9f1. If you're using an older version, the icons might look a bit different, but should work the same.)*